# the method in the type is not applicable for the arguments - but it should be (jsp)

Tags: java, jsp

In my Java class `DBManager` I have a method

```
alterRights(int, HashMap<Integer,Right>)
```

In my JSP file I do

```
HashMap<Integer,Right> radios = new HashMap<Integer,Right>();
```

Then I add a few items and then I do

```
dbm.alterRights(alterKlausurID, radios);
```

(`dbm` is an instance of `DBManager`)

And here the exception is thrown. It says: "The method alterRights(int, HashMap) in the type DBManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, HashMap)". In a former version, the method actually was `alterRights(int, HashMap<Integer,String>)`, but I changed it and it even worked until I changed something else. I didn't even touch this method or anything that is connected to it. For me it seems that the JSP file loads an older version of `dbm` but I don't know how this is even possible.

Comment: Just clean and recompile your project.

Comment: How? I'm working with Eclipse

Comment: I did "clean" but "Build Project" is disabled for me.

Comment: "Build Automatically" was checked. I'll try it manually

Comment: If "Build Automatically" is enabled, "Clean" alone is enough to trigger a full build of the project.

Comment: I tried both - Clean and Build manually and just Clean when Build Automatically was enabled - nothing worked for me, I'm still getting the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The usual problem here is that either JSP or `DBManager` wasn't compiled after the change.

Make sure you compile everything in your project. If you let your application server compile JSPs for you, change your build to compile them together with the rest of the code (then, you'd catch such problems while building the project).

In the meantime, read the documentation of your application server and find out how you can flush the JSP compile cache. Chances are that an old version of the compiled JSP is hanging around there. If you can't figure this out, undeploy your application, shut down the app server, start it again, deploy again.